# calculate total of group in grouping view of splist

Tags: jsom, view, grouping

I need to calculate the number of group in my grouping view of SharePoint list.
we can also calculate the number of different value in the column.

Any idea how we can do that using JSOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `renderListData` function on a list with JSOM to do the grouping.

Example:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", "SP.ClientContext", () => { 
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var viewXml = `<View>
                        <Aggregations Value='On'>
                            <FieldRef Name='Month' Type='COUNT'/>
                        </Aggregations>
                        <Query>
                            <Where>
                                <IsNotNull>
                                    <FieldRef Name='Month' Type='Text'/>
                                </IsNotNull>
                            </Where>
                        <GroupBy Collapse='TRUE' GroupLimit='100'>
                            <FieldRef Name='Month' />
                        </GroupBy>
                        <OrderBy>
                            <FieldRef Name='Month' Ascending='TRUE' />
                        </OrderBy>
                    </Query>
                </View>`;
    var result = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListTitle').renderListData(viewXml);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(() => {
        var res = JSON.parse( result.get_value());
        console.log("Group Count: ",  res.Row.length); 
        console.log("res", res);
    },(s,a) => {
        console.log("err",a.get_message());
    });
});
```

Comment: oh thank you Andres ; i found this one also http://spjsblog.com/2009/11/25/count-groups-in-grouped-list-view/ and it works